# How to use TrustedUUID?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For a while, I have been experimenting with NBT Data on Minecraft. Recently, I wanted to make a fox that trusts both me and a friend of mine, and I know this is possible, as they have the tag `TrustedUUID`.

However, I don't know how to use it. There are no tutorials about using this tag, and the Wikipedia, while mentioning it, does not give a good explanation. How can I use this to make a fox that trusts me and my friend?

I have tried to use only my friend's UUID, which did not work. I saw something about "M" and "L," but do not know how to use them. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: What were the commands you tried?

Answer (score 3):

You have to get your `UUIDMost` and `UUIDLeast`.

To get those, use a website like http://mapmaking.fr/uuid/ or any other website that can show your `UUID` with `UUIDMost` and `UUIDLeast`.

For example if you search me up (EpicProKillerFTW), you would see 3 things.

```
UUID: 4d05a07a36ad4bc4854217220ba9a219

UUIDMost: 5550018562567785412

UUIDLeast: -8844481283210239463
```

Once you get those, you can get your fox to be trusted by you and your friend using the Data Merge command:

```
/data merge entity <the fox's UUID> {
    TrustedUUIDs:[
    {
       L: <your UUIDLeast>L, 
       M: <your UUIDMost>L
    }, 
    {
       L: <your friend's UUIDLeast>L, 
       M: <your friend's UUIDMost>L
    }]
}
```

What the Data Merge command should look like:

```
/data merge entity 06de3220-88ae-4cf8-9f40-55135415a6b7 {TrustedUUIDs:[{L: -8844481283210239463L, M: 5550018562567785412L}, {L: -6334564698302257369L, M: -8038687027037716246L}]}
```

Alternatively, you can use the Summon command:

```
/summon fox ~ ~ ~ {
    TrustedUUIDs:[
    {
       L: <your UUIDLeast>L, 
       M: <your UUIDMost>L
    }, 
    {
       L: <your friend's UUIDLeast>L, 
       M: <your friend's UUIDMost>L
    }]
}
```

What the Summon command should look like:

```
/summon fox ~ ~ ~ {TrustedUUIDs:[{L: -8844481283210239463L, M: 5550018562567785412L}, {L: -6334564698302257369L, M: -8038687027037716246L}]}
```

Do note that you need to have the `L` at the end of the `UUID`.

It only works with 2 people, you and your friend. If you want others, then it won't work. I've tried it but only lets you have 2 `TrustedUUIDs`.

I hope this helped.

Comment: If someone figures out how to have more than 2 TrustedUUIDs, please say so.